# OpenSSL Server Permission Denied

Tags: server, permissions, openssl, certificates

I'm working with OpenSSL making certs for a homework assignment and my professor hasn't responded to my email questions. I'm trying to start a simple web server using s_server. First I have to combine the secret key and the cert into one file. I used
    cp server.key server.pem
and that went fine, no errors, then I used
    cat server.crt >> server.pem 
and I get bash: server.pem: Permission denied, even using sudo, and I can't figure out why. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -l server.pem`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 986 Sep 7 12:08 server.pem

Comment: Does it work by doing `sudo bash -c 'cat server.crt >> server.pem'`?

Comment: It doesn't return an error message, but the prompts disappear and after trying to launch the server as instructed using "openssl s_server -cert server.pem -www" the server doesn't work ("Server not found" in Firefox)

Comment: Does the server.crt contain the exact certificate needed, or is there part in the server.pem file that is needed as well?

Comment: According to the assignment, I need to combine the secret key and the certificate into one file. The instructions say "cp server.key server.pem" and then "cat server.crt >> server.pem" and then supposedly I should be able to launch the server.

Comment: Have you checked if the server.pem file indeed contains the contents of both server.crt and server.key?  `cat server.key` `cat server.crt` and `cat server.pem`